# Java count number total number of words and their character length

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

How do I create a program using arrays where the user enters a string, it checks to see how many words have x amount of letters then prints the total amount of words. For example if user enters:

> The     user  539537g is coolio8fsd

The number of words is 6: **"The"**, **"User"**, **"g"** , **"is"**, **"coolio"**, **"fsd"**. The program considers anything non-letter to be word separator, which would be numbers,symbols and spaces.

So it the program should output:

> This string has a total of 6 words.
>
> One 1-letter word
>
> One 2-letter word
>
> Two 3-letter word
>
> One 4-letter word
>
> One 6-letter word

Comment: Can the output be "2 3-letter words"?

Comment: Consider a big map for all the numbers names if you want this kind of output. Otherwise you can take @bradimus question as an advice that you should use `Integers` for example instead if `Strings` for the numbering the appearances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method of a string with a regex, to split the string into an array of words (Strings), and then count the strings that have a specified length.

```
// This regex finds all sequences of whitespace and numerical digits
s.split("\\s*[^A-z]\\s*|[\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams will work here.

```
// I'm assuming you can get the input from somewhere
// maybe a scanner
String input = "The user 539537g is coolio8fsd"; 

// Split on any non-letter
String[] words = input.split("[^A-z]"); 

Map<Long, Long> wordCounts = 
    Arrays.stream(words)                            // Stream the words
          .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())                // Filter out the empty ones
          .map(String::length)                      // Map each string to its length
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i, Collectors.counting());  // Create a map with length as key and count as value

System.out.println("There are " + wordCounts.size() + " words.");
wordCounts.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(v + " " + k + "-letter words"));
```

I did manage to do this in one line, but the readability is reduced. This seems a good balance.